# Programmatically create new attribute set while inheriting from another

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

I am programmatically creating attributes and attribute sets. The attributes work like they should, but with the attribute sets I have a problem.

When I create an attribute set, I can not let it inherit from another set (for example the default set). I have searched a lot but could not find any good info that could help me further.

My first thought there should be some function that lets you duplicate a set and edit it. I could not find it.

My second thought was recreating the whole set, but I could not find a function to get the groups from an attribute set, which I do want.

I'm pretty new to Magento, so sorry if I just missed something, but I am currently stuck. Any solutions / suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After trying out again, messing up a lot and finally finding the correct answer, this works:

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->getResource()
                  ->getEntityType()
                  ->getId(); //product entity type

$attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                  ->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId)
                  ->setAttributeSetName("test_set");

$attributeSet->validate();
$attributeSet->save();

$attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($entityTypeId)->save();
```

You need to save before you do `initFromSekeleton()`. Otherwise it just won't work.

Comment: Like Robbie said, you can just use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api::create` to do all this for you

Answer (score 10):

See how the attribute sets are created (inherited) from the backend. Check this method: `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_SetController::saveAction()`.
In that method there is this line that 'clones' the attribute set:

```
$model->initFromSkeleton($this->getRequest()->getParam('skeleton_set'));
```

Where `->getParam('skeleton_set')` is the attribute set to be cloned.
Basically you need to do something like this:

```
$cloneSetId = 4;//or anything else
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId(); //product entity type
$model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set'); //instantiate the model
$model->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);//attribute set is used for products
$model->setAttributeSetName('Attribute set name here');//set the attribute set name
$attributeSet->save(); // save before initFromSkeleton
$model->initFromSkeleton($cloneSetId);//clone one attribute set
$model->save();//save the new attribute set
//do other modifications here
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems that this code somehow only copies the groups, and not the attributes in those groups..

Comment: This means I might have missed something. Because in the `initFromSkeleton` method there is this line `$newGroup->setAttributes($newAttributes);`. This should set some attributes. Make sure you clone a valid set, also you can debug the `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_SetController::saveAction()` and try to simulate it in your code. that one seams to work.

Comment: It is a valid ID (I just use 4, which is an existing, default set), but I can't find anything to fix it :S

Answer (score 10):

Just a note, it appears that the attribute set API model can do this itself:

```
$newSetName    = 'My New Set';
$originalSetId = 4; // the set to base the new one off

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api */
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_set_api')
    ->create($newSetName, $originalSetId);
```

Comment: Oh nice. This is a much better solution.. maybe it didn't exist 2 years ago